How can I count Mongoose Schema documents with a filter?
I am trying to count the entries in a database (w/ a Schema) while only filtering for a particular user (filter), but it keeps not working.
Here is my code:
WarningSchema.find({ user_id: user.id.toString() }).countDocuments((err, count) => {
    client.users.cache.get(user.id).send({
        embeds: [
            new EmbedBuilder().setTitle('Notice').setColor('#2B2D31').setDescription(`You have received an official warning on behalf of the RCA Moderation Team.`).addFields({ name: 'Moderator', value: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`, inline: true }, { name: 'Warning #', value: `${count}`, inline: true }, { name: 'Content', value: reason, inline: false })
        ]
    })

    // ...

})

I have tried using the find method in an independent function and assigning it to a variable:
const count = WarningSchema.find({ user_id: user.id.toString() }).countDocuments().exec();

However, that doesn't work, either.
My current codes just returns:
warning.countDocuments({ user_id: '1096621476859351102' })

(Counting warnings for a Discord bot)

The return value of countDocuments is a Promise.
Therefore the async problem seems to be the cause.
Using async/await (or you can use .then()) it will look like this:
try {
    const count = await WarningSchema.countDocuments({ user_id: user.id.toString() });

    client.users.cache.get(user.id).send({
        embeds: [
            new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Notice')
                .setColor('#2B2D31')
                .setDescription('You have received an official warning on behalf of the RCA Moderation Team.')
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Moderator', value: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Warning #', value: `${count}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Content', value: reason, inline: false }
                )
        ]
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error counting documents:', err);
}


Great, thank you so much!
